# XML variable can't be changed or accessed (AS3)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have currently created a class that can be used to access all of my xml data in AS3. The problem I have had though is with changing variables inside xmlIsLoaded function. When I traced the xml variable it shows the xml data, but I when I traced it in the loadPanelData() function, I got a null reference. In the code below I experimented with an int variable, and when I tested it, it traced the initial value of 0 and did not change to 2.

Obviously there is something I am not understanding when it comes to how xmlIsLoaded is working, but it is necessary to access the xml data (when I just do a regular function without listeners, the xml variable is empty and traces nothing). Hopefully someone has a solution since I am new to using XML with AS3.

```
 public class XMLLoader extends EventDispatcher 
    {
        var xml:XML;
        var productElement:XMLList;
        var productElementXML:XML;
        var num:int = 0;

        public function XMLLoader() 
        {
            var xmlUrl:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("Project/XMLFiles/PagesXML.xml"));
            xmlUrl.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlIsLoaded);
        }

        private function xmlIsLoaded(e:Event)
        {
            xml = new XML(e.target.data);
            num = 2;
            //trace("this is the xml starting point" + xml.pages + "this is the xml in the class");

            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }

        public function loadPanelData()
        {
             trace("product element test" + num);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define "[access modifiers](http://greenethumb.com/article/27/public-private-protected-internal-access-modifiers-in-as3/)" to your variables. i.e.

```
public var xml:XML;
public var productElement:XMLList;
public var productElementXML:XML;
public var num:int = 0;
```

Second, when do you call method **loadPanelData()**? You should call it after the **xmlIsLoaded** method has executed.

Either listen for that `Event.COMPLETE` event by attaching an eventListener and creating an event handler (code not shown?) to execute and trace the value of **num**, or call the method directly within the **xmlIsLoaded** method.